# Creating a Project in VS19 to work with an Angular Frontend and ASP.NET Backend

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript, wcfserviceclient

I am trying to set up an Angular8 project to work with an already existing WCF Service and ASP.NET backend. The goals being to get the project set up in Visual Studio 2019. In addition to getting the actual project set up how to then communicate to the WCF Service from the Angular Project to receive the data?

I have tried various tutorials but most of them use ASP.NET Core instead of just ASP.NET. I have gotten far with setting up a test project with a ASP.NET MVC application then forcing it to route to Angular but that is still posing some problems. If someone has some advice for setting up the Angular project to work with just an empty ASP.NET project that would best. None of the test projects I have created thus far are exactly what I am looking for, so posting them here would just cause confusion.

Expected: A demo project to prove that a project can be set up where Angular8 can communicate to the WCF Service, get some data from it then display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ASP.NET Boilerplate Framework: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/ this framework starter templates for both types of ASP.NET projects: Core and MVC.

> ASP.NET Boilerplate (ABP) is an open source and well-documented application framework. It's not just a framework, it also provides a strong architectural model based on Domain Driven Design, with all the best practices in mind.

I believe that is a good way to start. Also you can create project using either: Angular, Vue or React.

Hope that helps you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! We are wanting to avoid using MVC if possible. I am looking into boiler plate to see if it could potentially be a solution though!

Comment: You can create a full project ASP.NET Core + Angular also with ASP.NET Boilerplate.

Comment: The backend is ASP.NET. I mentioned MVC but they told me they would prefer creating it with an empty ASP.NET project. I am not familiar with ASP.NET, I am not sure what the difference is or how exactly MVC interacts with ASP.NET. Do you know a way I can create it with just an empty ASP.NET project? I am mostly just aiming to prove that Angular can play nice with their ASP.NET and WCF Service.

Comment: I recommend you to download a starter sample and play. Just download follow the instructions and you will see how smoothly the things will be.